# Hide Site Column to Readers?

Tags: sharepoint, moss

in a List i have one 'Status' field that should be accessible to only Owners and to the Viewers/Readers it should not be accessible. Do anybody can guide me how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can, your view still is visible if the users know how to reach the default views of your list, if its not a security issue, you can use this:

- Open your All Items View (/Lists/MyList/AllItems.aspx)
- Edit the Page
- Add the same List as a WebPart, twice
- Delete the original webpart (the one with the Change View drop down)
- Edit your WebParts and configure your views
- In the Toolpart, on the Advanced [+] set Audience Targetting to your desired Groups
- Done!

Answer (score 1):

Either that or you can create a workflow that copies the item to a new list with its metadata, but without that specific column and only give the viewers rights to see that list.

Answer (score 1):

If the question is one of security (it usually is, else just use a view), you can't lock down specific columns. You can find techniques to hide them, but then you're just plugging holes.

The workflow approach recommended by KoenVosters is probably the only secured way I can think of delivering this without coding.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible out of the box, but I came across this [tool](http://splistdisplaysetting.codeplex.com/) that will help to archive this with ease